# How can I parse this response in flutter and have values from response in text field from both the arrays in API response?

Tags: json, api, parsing, flutter

I'm using Flutter/Dart. [This endpoint](http://app.webcraft.co.in/eschool/parent/routejson?parent_id=2&student_id=1) gives me this response:

```
{"listroute":[{"id":"1","route_title":"Brooklyn East","no_of_vehicle":null,"fare":"101.00","note":null,"is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:49:21","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","vehicles":[{"vec_route_id":"1","id":"1","vehicle_no":"101","vehicle_model":"101","manufacture_year":"2000","driver_name":"arvind","driver_licence":"544575854","driver_contact":"1305442045","note":"","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:54:13"}]},{"id":"2","route_title":"Brooklyn South","no_of_vehicle":null,"fare":"1010.00","note":null,"is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:50:06","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","vehicles":[{"vec_route_id":"3","id":"3","vehicle_no":"2145","vehicle_model":"425","manufacture_year":"2017","driver_name":"amit","driver_licence":"4526320125","driver_contact":"23054420456","note":"","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:57:23"},{"vec_route_id":"2","id":"2","vehicle_no":"1010","vehicle_model":"242","manufacture_year":"2016","driver_name":"abhisekh","driver_licence":"4526320125","driver_contact":"23054420456","note":"","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:56:41"}]},{"id":"3","route_title":"Brooklyn West","no_of_vehicle":null,"fare":"100.00","note":null,"is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:51:00","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","vehicles":[]},{"id":"4","route_title":"Uppal","no_of_vehicle":null,"fare":"101.00","note":null,"is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:51:22","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","vehicles":[{"vec_route_id":"6","id":"3","vehicle_no":"2145","vehicle_model":"425","manufacture_year":"2017","driver_name":"amit","driver_licence":"4526320125","driver_contact":"23054420456","note":"","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:57:23"},{"vec_route_id":"5","id":"2","vehicle_no":"1010","vehicle_model":"242","manufacture_year":"2016","driver_name":"abhisekh","driver_licence":"4526320125","driver_contact":"23054420456","note":"","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:56:41"},{"vec_route_id":"4","id":"1","vehicle_no":"101","vehicle_model":"101","manufacture_year":"2000","driver_name":"arvind","driver_licence":"544575854","driver_contact":"1305442045","note":"","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:54:13"}]},{"id":"5","route_title":"MAHE","no_of_vehicle":null,"fare":"101.00","note":null,"is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:51:37","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","vehicles":[{"vec_route_id":"7","id":"2","vehicle_no":"1010","vehicle_model":"242","manufacture_year":"2016","driver_name":"abhisekh","driver_licence":"4526320125","driver_contact":"23054420456","note":"","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:56:41"}]},{"id":"6","route_title":"CMD Chowk","no_of_vehicle":null,"fare":"200.00","note":null,"is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-02 12:51:58","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","vehicles":[]},{"id":"9","route_title":"x","no_of_vehicle":null,"fare":"10.00","note":null,"is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-11 07:22:46","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","vehicles":[]},{"id":"10","route_title":"xy","no_of_vehicle":null,"fare":"10.00","note":null,"is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-11 07:22:53","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","vehicles":[]},{"id":"11","route_title":"mmm","no_of_vehicle":null,"fare":"10.00","note":null,"is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-11 11:48:02","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","vehicles":[]}],"childs":[{"transport_fees":"0.00","vehroute_id":"6","student_session_id":"1","fees_discount":"0.00","class_id":"1","class":"Nursery A","section_id":"1","section":"A","id":"1","admission_no":"1","roll_no":"01052018","admission_date":"2018-05-30","firstname":"Amit","lastname":"Teja","image":"uploads\/student_images\/no_image.png","mobileno":"09021902190","email":"amit@mailinator.com","state":null,"city":null,"pincode":null,"religion":"Teja","cast":"Gen","dob":"2016-07-06","current_address":"ttetet\r\nasdasdasd","previous_school":"","guardian_is":"father","permanent_address":"ttetet\r\nasdasdasd","category_id":"1","adhar_no":"iewk123kaqws12","samagra_id":"iewk123kaqws12","bank_account_no":"9999999999999999999999","bank_name":"CITY Bank","ifsc_code":"city000010","guardian_name":"Sumit","guardian_relation":"Father","guardian_phone":"8309632153","guardian_address":"ttetet\r\nasdasdasd","is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-06 11:52:43","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","father_name":"Sumit","father_phone":"Teja","father_occupation":"Business","mother_name":"Sumitra","mother_phone":"9876543211","mother_occupation":"House Wife","guardian_occupation":"Business","gender":"Male","rte":"Yes","guardian_email":"sumit@mailinato.com"},{"transport_fees":"0.00","vehroute_id":"0","student_session_id":"2","fees_discount":"0.00","class_id":"1","class":"Nursery A","section_id":"1","section":"A","id":"2","admission_no":"2","roll_no":"01052019","admission_date":"2018-06-01","firstname":"vibhav","lastname":"Teja","image":"uploads\/student_images\/no_image.png","mobileno":"7894561230","email":"vibhav@gmail.com","state":null,"city":null,"pincode":null,"religion":"Teja","cast":"Gen","dob":"2018-06-09","current_address":"ttetet\r\nasdasdasd","previous_school":"","guardian_is":"father","permanent_address":"ttetet\r\nasdasdasd","category_id":"1","adhar_no":"iewk123kaqws12","samagra_id":"iewk123kaqws12","bank_account_no":"125423625642","bank_name":"City Bank","ifsc_code":"12542362","guardian_name":"Sumit","guardian_relation":"Father","guardian_phone":"8309632153","guardian_address":"ttetet\r\nasdasdasd","is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-06 11:29:26","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","father_name":"Sumit","father_phone":"Teja","father_occupation":"Business","mother_name":"Sumitra","mother_phone":"9876543211","mother_occupation":"House Wife","guardian_occupation":"Business","gender":"Male","rte":"Yes","guardian_email":"sumit@mailinato.com"},{"transport_fees":"0.00","vehroute_id":"6","student_session_id":"11","fees_discount":"0.00","class_id":"2","class":"Nursery B","section_id":"2","section":"B","id":"5","admission_no":"1234-A1","roll_no":"0105202010","admission_date":"2018-06-11","firstname":"Rajat","lastname":"Teja","image":"uploads\/student_images\/no_image.png","mobileno":"07697019875","email":"rajat@gmail.com","state":null,"city":null,"pincode":null,"religion":"Teja","cast":"","dob":"2018-06-14","current_address":"ttetet\r\nasdasdasd","previous_school":"","guardian_is":"father","permanent_address":"ttetet\r\nasdasdasd","category_id":"3","adhar_no":"","samagra_id":"","bank_account_no":"","bank_name":"","ifsc_code":"","guardian_name":"Sumit","guardian_relation":"Father","guardian_phone":"8309632153","guardian_address":"ttetet\r\nasdasdasd","is_active":"no","created_at":"2018-06-11 07:35:54","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","father_name":"Sumit","father_phone":"Teja","father_occupation":"Business","mother_name":"Sumitra","mother_phone":"9876543211","mother_occupation":"House Wife","guardian_occupation":"Business","gender":"Female","rte":"No","guardian_email":""}]}
```

How can I parse this type of output?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a question, you will get much better answers if you provide code. Add what you have tried so far. Also please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should give us examples or atleast what you've tried to us so we are able to help. Regardless have you tried this: https://flutter.io/json/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the question already seems to be parsed. May be you want to know how to use the received data. Here's an example of it.

```
class HomeState extends State<Home> {
List listRoute = [];

Future getData() async {
    http.Response res = await http.get(
        'http://app.webcraft.co.in/eschool/parent/routejson?parent_id=2&student_id=1');
    Map mapRes = json.decode(res.body);
    print('Response from server: $mapRes');
    setState(() {
    listRoute = mapRes['listroute'];
    });
}

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('HTTP demo'),
    ),
    body: listRoute.length == 0
        ? new Container()
        : new ListView(
            children: listRoute
                .map((route) => new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(route['route_title']),
                    subtitle: new Text(route['fare'])))
                .toList(),
            ),
    );
}
}
```

Or may be you need to understand that, what you have received is a `Map` where value of key `listroute` is a list which you need to iterate.

OR

If you are unable to access some other key or data in the map please ask in the comment.

**NOTE:** If you are unable to understand/read the data, there are several sites to view json data in pretty format like http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: hey, thanks actully i need to parse values of both listroute and vihicles array values and use it on a text

Comment: i need to show vehicles value too in text along with other listroutes values

Comment: @AyushJainWebCraftIT getting this error - Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (24765): Receiver: null
E/flutter (24765): Tried calling: []("BankName")

Comment: in my case not list response fetched in textview but every time getting this error

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string you can use `jsonDecode` or `json.decode`

```
import 'dart:convert' show jsonDecode, json;

Map<String,dynamic> parseResponse(String response) {
  return jsonDecode(response);
}
```